How can I test a Fastify HTTP/2 Cleartext server?
I'm switching a Fastify server using HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 Cleartext. I can manually test that it works fine. But all requests in tests using inject() now fail with 505 status code.
Looking at https://github.com/fastify/light-my-request it seems to be unsupported. Is there an alternative HTTP injection library which works for this?
If not, and I need to follow https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Guides/Testing/#testing-with-a-running-server, that's not trivial either: undici and built-in fetch don't support H2C. I tried fetch-h2, but couldn't get it to work.
So I guess my remaining options are:

Make requests manually with the http2 module. It's too low-level to use conveniently, but can be wrapped. However, I've run into a separate issue when trying to make requests including file fields: How to POST formdata including a file field with http2 module in Node?.
Run under HTTP/1.1 in test environment only, and use inject (and somehow distinguish integration tests which do need HTTP/2 from unit tests).

Anything better?

You may use the same (beta) client that Fastify is using: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/test/http2/constraint.test.js
